# Retrieving objects

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I made a GET function that will retrieve posts and will make it available only to a particular user as well as its friends list. To make this work partially, I developed a raw query to get my desired output, and somehow it works fine for me.

Now, I am trying to learn making queries in django without implementing raw query, so I am trying to maximize the Django ORM and not use raw query but I'm kinda stucked and kept wondering how I am gonna be able to make my queryset works without using raw query.

this is my raw query:

```
 FeedMedia.objects.raw("""SELECT DISTINCT feed_media.*
            FROM feed_media
            INNER JOIN feed ON feed_media.feed_id = feed.id
            INNER JOIN media ON feed_media.media_id = media.id
            INNER JOIN profile ON profile.id = feed.profile_id
            INNER JOIN gosam_friend_profile ON gosam_friend_profile.profile_id = feed.profile_id
            INNER JOIN friendship_friend ON friendship_friend.id = gosam_friend_profile.gosam_friend_id
            WHERE friendship_friend.to_user_id = %(friend)s
            OR gosam_friend_profile.profile_id = %(profile)s""",
                                           params={'friend': request.user.pk, 'profile': profile.pk})
```

FeedMedia model:

```
 # Junction Table for Feed and Media
 class FeedMedia(models.Model):
   media = models.ForeignKey(Media, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
   feed = models.ForeignKey(Feed, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)

   class Meta:
      db_table = 'feed_media'
```

Feed model:

```
class Feed(models.Model):
   profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
   message = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, unique=False)
   type = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, unique=False)
   category = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, unique=False)
   priority_level = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=False, unique=False)
   origin_location = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, unique=False)
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

   class Meta:
     db_table = 'feed'
```

GosamFriendProfile model:

```
# Junction Table for Gosam Friends and Profile
class GosamFriendProfile(models.Model):
     gosam_friend = models.ForeignKey(Friend, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
     profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)

     class Meta:
        db_table = 'gosam_friend_profile'
```

- friendship_friend belongs to django-friendship

Comment: Can you add your models?

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot, wait I'll include it.